# TSQL update date with today from datetimeoffset column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetimeoffset

I have a table with 3 columns:
ID (int, PK)
Time (datetimeoffset)
StoredValue (int)

I need to update only the date in the Time column with today, **each row according to the timezone that is already stored in the datetimeoffset** (but dont change the time or timezone info). For example if the stored value is: 2014-10-08 08:25:46.0000000 +04:00 and Today for that timezone is: 2014-10-20, it should become:2014-10-20 08:25:46.0000000 +04:00 but if today is still 2014-10-19 for that timezone, it should be set to: 2014-10-19 08:25:46.0000000 +04:00.

How can I do that in TSQL?

UPDATE:
Possibly messy and incomplete answer that does not update correctly each row according to the timezone, but based on the answers below:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIMEOFFSET = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
DECLARE @date2 datetimeoffset(4) = '12-10-25 12:32:10.1237 +01:0'
CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS(datepart(yyyy, @date), datepart(mm, @date), datepart(dd, @date), datepart(HH, @date2), datepart(MI, @date2), datepart(SS, @date2), datepart( MILLISECOND, @date2), CAST((FLOOR(DATEPART(TZ, @date2)) / 60) AS VARCHAR(10)), CAST((DATEPART(TZ,@date2)%60) AS VARCHAR(10)), 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @date DATETIMEOFFSET = '2013-01-31 10:02:12 +02:00'

select @date,CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, DATEADD(day, 18, @date))
```

Please check with above code.

Comment: this that not handle the updating of rows to today's date. Probably compute the difference betwen existing date and today then do this? Wrote above an incomplete answer. If you can improve/modify in that direction it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this !

```
 dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,timecolumn,getdate()),timecolumn)
```